# how can I get only one data frame or how to overwrite the data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, overwrite

df1 =

|  | name | age | branch | subject | date of joining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | 27 | Mechanical | Autocad | 01-08-2021 |
| 2 | Adam | 32 | Electrical | control sys | 14-08-2021 |
| 3 | Raj | 24 | Electrical | circuit | 20-08-2021 |
| 4 | Tim | 25 | Computers | clouding | 21-08-2021 |

df2= [['name','branch']]

print(df2)

|  | name | branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | Mechanical |
| 2 | Adam | Electrical |
| 3 | Raj | Electrical |
| 4 | Tim | Computers |

Now I have two data frames,

I need only **name** and **branch** columns and remove the remaining columns, all these operations should apply to the original df1.  I don't want separately df2

Comment: I don't understand the problem - do you mean that you want to essentially extract just the `name` and `branch` columns from df1 to make df2?

Comment: Simply, Overwrite the df1 only, df1= df1[['name','branch']] or del df1(after df2 created)

Comment: @Bashton Yes. I need  only **name** and **branch** and remove the remaining columns 
all these operations should apply to the original df1.

Comment: @Rajeev how to delete the df1 after d2 is created?

Comment: del df1
del df2
@usmansharif

Comment: @Rajeev is this data frame doesn't affect to original source of data right after del df1? because data is coming from MongoDB cloud

Comment: It will not affect, it is your local system(you are not running any db query)

Comment: @Rajeev oh okay. thanks dude your code worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, Overwrite the df1 only

df1= df1[['name','branch']]
or
df2= df1[['name','branch']]
del df1

To delete df1 or df2.
del df1
or
del df2

Based on requirement

Comment: df1= df1[['name','branch']]  this part worked for me. thanks 
it saved me a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set `df1` to `df2` or you can drop the columns from `df1`.

#### Method 1: drop in place

```
columns_to_drop = [x for x in df1.columns if x not in ['name','branch']]
df1.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
```

#### Method 2:

```
df1 = df1[['name','branch']]
```

Comment: df1= df1[['name','branch']] this worked for me , thanks for support dude